# MySQL Workbench Table Data Import Error Unhandled Exception: Could not determine delimiter

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

I have a database in MySQL Workbench with several tables already, and I need to write a query that is normal in most respects save one. For this query, I am not going to be selecting my results based on field matching criteria where all such records are returned, rather it is based off of a list of Key field values already obtained from a team member which are in an Excel file right now.

My tables have data on flight operations, airport schedules, and runways across the united states; usually 5 figures per table. Each table has an ID column indicating the Airport ID. My team member has isolated just the 661 Airport IDs we need to focus on and sent it to me in an Excel workbook which I in turn converted into a csv file called "Dep_Airport_IDs" shown below:
[image]

I thought it would be simplest just to upload this as a new table and then run a join operation of my other tables on it on their Airport ID fields. But whenever I try to upload it using the Table Data Import Wizard, I get the following Error:
[image]

[image]

Is this because there is only 1 column? And is there a way around this or is my approach thought process just extremely flawed here? I must admit this is my first time using MySQL in over a year now.

This is how the same input looks as a text file rather than a csv file:
[image]

Comment: What does your CSV data look like in text format?

Comment: @PM77-1 I added another screenshot of what that looks like about 8 hours ago.

Comment: If you have not done so already, review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html and check field and line separators. I'm afraid I will not be able to help beyond that.